# What does the blue circle in the RStudio environment mean?

Tags: rstudio, environment

I have a dataframe called "test" in the environment:  [image: test: 392324 obs. of 8 variables]

I want to add a column that assigns an increasing unique integer to each row of data, so I ran this code to create the column "count":

```
test$count <- 1:nrow(test)
```

It works and show as this in the environment: [image: test 392324 obs. of 9 variables]

I am concerned that the blue circle has disappeared (to the left of the word "test"). Is there a way to bring it back? I think "test" is still a dataframe, but it may have been changed to a matrix?

My issue is that the new column "count" makes it so we can no longer preview its contents without opening it fully, and this is less than ideal.

Comment: Can it be some sort of expansion of the variable to get more information about it?

Comment: Converted to images with descriptions. These images can be selected to obtain alternative text.

Comment: Yes, it is an expansion of the variable to provide more information. My question is, why did it disappear after I ran the line of code above?